# JavaFX Maven Compile Error

Tags: java, maven, javafx

Maven cant build my JavaFX Project, its runs perfectly fine via Intellij. It cant find all the JavaFX packages.

```
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!

[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to /home/christian/Projects/timetracking-converter/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] /home/christian/Projects/timetracking-converter/src/main/java/com/mayobirne/controller/ConverterController.java:[8,25] error: package javafx.application does not exist
```

it shows an error for all JavaFX-related imports

this is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mayobirne</groupId>
<artifactId>timetracking-converter</artifactId>
<name>timetracking-converter</name>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>mayobirne</name>
</organization>

<properties>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>timetracking-converter</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.mayobirne.MainApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.mayobirne.MainApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>

    <!-- MigLayout -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
        <artifactId>miglayout-javafx</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- EXCEL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Project is available on Github: https://github.com/mayobirne/timetracking-converter

Comment: nevermind found it, had to add:

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <systemPath>/home/christian/Programme/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0/runtime/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
            <scope>system</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: My guess is that the compilation was done with Openjdk instead of Oracle Java, which doesn't contain Javafx classes.

Comment: Try this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-individual-file-encoding.html